# How to push my local branch to my remote branch if other people pushed their work to my remote branch

Tags: git

I'm pushing my local branch's commit (may 2022) to my remote branch(last time commit April 2022). However, other people pushed their work to my remote branch(April 2022) which I didn't pull yet.

I need to pull my remote branch(April 2022 which currently contains other people's work) to merge that person's work to my local, then I can push my local branch (contains changes I made in May 2022) to remote.

However, I worry that if I pull that person's work(april 2022) to my local branch, my recent works during may 2022 will be overwritten. That person only added several files to my branch. Is there anyway to merge his work to my branch that only download the files he added but keep my recent works I did during may 2022?

Comment: Git isn't about files, or changes, really: it's about *commits*. When you run `git pull` you're really running (1) `git fetch`, followed by (2) a Git command of your choice where you are telling Git to *combine work* by combining any new commits you got in step 1 with any commits you already had that need the kind of combining you've chosen. As long as you've made *commits*, this literally can't *overwrite* anything, because commits are read-only (completely) and permanent (mostly).

Comment: There are a *lot* of fiddly details in all of this, but the key is to understand what a commit is, what it does for you, how Git normally only ever *adds* commits, and how the files you see and work on / with aren't in Git at all: it's only the *commits* (and their saved snapshots) that are in Git. Then you can understand the `git merge` and `git rebase` commands that accomplish the "combine work" phase of the *second* half of `git pull`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you explicitly force it, Git won't override any of your changes.

But it sounds like this is pretty straightforward to accomplish.  All you're doing is introducing the changes that others made into your local branch and republishing the branch.

Here's what I'd do.

1. `git fetch`
2. `get merge`
3. Resolve any merge conflicts that arise (you'll need to **talk with the other developers** about this)
4. `git push`